# Static Get Method Causing Calculation Error In Child Class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction

Sorry if this is formatted badly. I'm new to SO and still learning the ins and outs!
I have in my main method this:

```
public class DriverP4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AccountHolder[] accountHolder = new AccountHolder[12];{
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//OVER 60
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1995);//UNDER 30
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1992);//BETWEEN 30-60
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1955);//OVER 60
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",2008);//UNDER 30
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1987);//BETWEEN 30-60
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
            new AccountHolder("Bob","2402 Wilson Rd.","Oxford","MS",1902);//BIKER
        }

        Account[] account = new Account[]{
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[0],0,2001,true),
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[1],0,2002,true),
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[2],0,2003,true),
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[3],0,2004,false),
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[4],0,2005,false),
                new HealthAccount(accountHolder[5],0,2006,false),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[6], 0, "Sport", 1, 2006, 2007, 0),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[7], 0, "Sport", 2, 2007, 2008, 1),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[8], 0, "Scooter", 3, 2008, 2009, 0),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[9], 0, "Scooter", 4, 2009, 2010, 1),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[10], 0, "Recreational", 5, 2010, 2011, 0),
                new MotorcycleAccount(accountHolder[11], 0, "Recreational", 6, 2011, 2012, 1)
        };

        System.out.println("||| HEALTH ACCOUNTS |||");
        System.out.println("################################################################");
        for(int i = 0; i < account.length;i++){
            account[i].printAccount();
            if (i == 5) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("||| MOTORCYCLE ACCOUNTS ||||");
                System.out.println("################################################################");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("If you would like to see the data again, please re-run the program.");
    }
}
```

And I am trying to access the age and smoker status from both, and then pass it to my HealthAccount Class' calculate method:

```
 public double calculateMonthlyPremium() {  
        setBasePlanAmount(2500+8300);
        double monthlyPremium = getBasePlanAmount();
        int age = CURRENT_YEAR-AccountHolder.getBirthYear();
        if(smoker){
            monthlyPremium+=500;
        }
        if(age > 60){
            monthlyPremium+=200;
        }
        if(age < 30) {
            monthlyPremium=getBasePlanAmount();
        }
        if (age >= 30 && age <= 60) {
            monthlyPremium = getBasePlanAmount();
        }
        return monthlyPremium/12;
    }
```

In my AccountHolder class I have to make my getYear method static, but then it only uses 1902 for the age of my calculations. I need it to iterate through each account's individual age for the calculations to be accurate. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: _"In my AccountHolder class I have to make my getYear method static"_ - That cannot be correct.  Each `AccountHolder` can have a different year, so it must be an instance method, not static.  Please explain why you believe it must be static.

Comment: It says that I cant reference getBirthYear() from a static context